# Session Attribute issue Vaadin 24

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I have trouble understading how VaadinSessions and UI works.

I have my class that takes the id and other information of SampleClient and use it as a URL:

```
@Route(value = "URL-of-page/:sampleClientID?", layout = MainLayout.class)
@RolesAllowed("USER")
public class DocumentazioneEntita extends Div implements BeforeEnterObserver {
    
    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        this.client = (SampleClient) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("client");
        System.out.println("client inside override " + client);
        if (this.client == null) {
            Notification.show("No client selected", 3000, Notification.Position.BOTTOM_START);
            navigateToMain(event);
            return;
        }
        this.idClienteString = (String) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("idCliente");
        System.out.println("ID CLIENT STRING: " + idClienteString);
        Optional<Long> sampleClientId = event.getRouteParameters().get(SAMPLECLIENT_ID).map(Long::parseLong);
        if (sampleClientId.isPresent()) {
            Optional<SampleClient> sampleClientFromBackend = sampleClientService.get(sampleClientId.get());
            if (sampleClientFromBackend.isPresent()) {
                populateForm(sampleClientFromBackend.get());
            } else {
                Notification.show(
                        String.format("Client not found, ID = %d", sampleClientId.get()),
                        3000, Notification.Position.BOTTOM_START);
                navigateToMain(event);
                return;
            }
            refreshGridData();
        } 
    }
    private Long idCliente = (Long) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("IdCliente");
  
    
    private SampleCoursesService sampleCoursesService;
    private SampleContactsService sampleContactsService;
    private SampleClientService sampleClientService;
    private SampleContacts contact;
    private SampleClient client;
    
    private String SAMPLECLIENT_ID = "sampleClientID";


    private Checkbox showArchivedCheckbox; // Define showArchivedCheckbox as a field
    private Grid<SampleContacts> dispositiviTable = new Grid<>(SampleContacts.class);; // Define dispositiviTable as a field
    private List<SampleContacts> contactsList; // Define contactsList as a field

    private Binder<SampleClient> binder = new Binder<>(SampleClient.class);

    private GenerateReport generateReport;
    public String idClienteString;
    

        public DocumentazioneEntita(SampleCoursesService sampleCoursesService, 
                                    SampleContactsService sampleContactsService, 
                                    SampleClientService sampleClientService, GenerateReport generateReport) {
            this.sampleCoursesService = sampleCoursesService;
            this.sampleContactsService = sampleContactsService;
            this.sampleClientService = sampleClientService;
            this.generateReport = generateReport;
            
            setId("documentazione-entita-view");
            setSizeFull();
            System.out.println("ID CLIENTE: " + idCliente); 
            System.out.println("ID CLIENTE STRING: sotto autowired " + idClienteString);
```

To better understand the situation i started debugging printing in the console the data i have.
Tthis is the output of my terminal:

```
ID CLIENTE: 1
ID CLIENTE STRING: sotto autowired null

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA SampleClient [capCliente=null, cfCliente=XYZ789, descrizioneCliente=null, emailCliente=bellali@it.it, idCliente=37, indirizzoCliente=789 Main St, insolvente=false, localitaCliente=New York, nomeCliente=John Smith, noteCliente=null, provinciaCliente=null, pivaCliente=1.23456789E8, sdiCliente=SDI123, telefonoCliente=1234567890]       
ID CLIENTE STRING: 37
```

So inside the  `@Override`i have my data outside of it i do not. why is the reason for that?
I wanted to be able to use the data of my SampleClient in my page freely but i can't figure it out why it just stays inside the before enter class.

Is worth noticing that in the previous page i got all the necessary information through Vaadin UI:

```
   private void navigateToEntityDocumentation(SampleClient client) {
        System.out.println("go to: " + client);
        if (client != null) {
            Long idCliente = client.getIdCliente();
            
            if (idCliente != null) {
                
                String idClienteString = idCliente.toString();
                UI.getCurrent().navigate("documentazione-entita/" + idClienteString);
                UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("idCliente", idClienteString);
                UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("client", client); 
            } else {
                // Log that idCliente is null
                System.out.println("Cliente not found " + client);
                UI.getCurrent().navigate("#");
            }
        } else {
            // Log that client is null
            System.out.println("Client does not exists");
            UI.getCurrent().navigate("#");
        }
    }
```

This is what my `System.out.println("go to: " + client);` outputs in the terminal, as a proof that i have a data flow from page to page.

```
go to: SampleClient [capCliente=null, cfCliente=XYZ789, descrizioneCliente=null, emailCliente=bellali@it.it, idCliente=37, indirizzoCliente=789 Main St, insolvente=false, localitaCliente=New York, nomeCliente=John Smith, noteCliente=null, provinciaCliente=null, pivaCliente=1.23456789E8, sdiCliente=SDI123, telefonoCliente=1234567890]
```

Comment: Typo in your magic-strings: `IdCliente` vs `idCliente`.  Use constants or suffer the consequences likes this...

Comment: @cfrick how would you made a constant in that code?

Comment: `public static final String SESSION_KEY_ID_CLIENTE = "idCliente"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, the problem here has nothing to do with `VaadinSession`.

Instead, the problem is that one part of the code uses `"IdCliente"` as the session attribute name and another part of the code uses `"idCliente"`. It's recommended to use a constant for magic string values like this to avoid these types of mistakes.

Comment: sometimes i suck and can be very very dumb thank you Leif plus how would you make constants here?